# Is there way to recover after EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS crash?

Tags: ios, swift, crash, foundation, nsthread

I am using one of standard system API that crashes sometimes. I was desperate to fix it, so I am trying to workaround it.
Is there a way to handle the crash in `GCD`'s background queue or in `NSThread` and restart this thread/queue?

Just in case, here is my crash: http://crashes.to/s/35846bd1b82 .

Comment: Technically?  Maybe yes.  But for the sake of best practice, I'm going to lie and say no, this is not possible.

Comment: Yeah, I understand your point, I love to create perfect software too. But what if you are in a situation when you are calling this iOS API 1000 times per hour and it crashes a couple of times every single day? What should I tell my customers? I would love to temporary recover from that crash and lately, when my app will be in background, restart it completly.

Comment: That crash appears to be in *your* code.

Comment: Really? How do you understand it? ProofReader is system component.

Comment: I agree that it is likely crashing in your code. Is ICfree not yours?

Comment: Of course, not! Everything after `[UITextChecker completionsForPartialWordRange:inString:language:]` (ProofReader, AppleSpell) are parts of system (iOS) spellchecking infrastructrure. Guys, yes, the code from Apple can crash.